# Create zip archive(bash script)

Tags: bash

My folders structure is:

- folder1
- folder2
- folder3
- zipFolder
- scriptFolder

scriptFolder for bash script
zipFolder for zip archive

Question: I want to create zip archive, which will be consist of folder1, folder2, folder3 and situated in zipFolder. How to write this script?

Comment: Use the [`zip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) command.

Comment: "How do I use UNIX tools?" questions not specific to scripting (or otherwise [unique to software development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) belong on [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by Rick, use [zip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) command:

`zip -r ../zipfolder/folders.zip ../folder1 ../folder2 ../folder3`